# Is there any way to use one AzureAD app for both frontend and backend

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have react front-end app and AWS lambda backend. I already integrated AzureAD authentication to my react app using MSAL. I wanted to clarify a couple of things

- after the user logs In to the front end i want to call one of my backend APIs and call the azure graph api via my backend service. for the backend azure interaction, I had to create another app in the azure ad. my question is can i use my frontend access token to call the azure graph api since my front-end access token belongs to a different app in the azure Ad? if not what would be the suggested way to do this kind of flow?
- is there any way to add the user role like `admin, manager, user` to the active directory and retrieve that role when the user logs in. my requirement is once a user logs in I need to display certain features to my front-end app based on roles. I have seen that there are things called scope but couldn't figure out if it satisfies my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

You have to create two Azure AD applications for authentication.

I created Azure AD **`ServerApp`** and exposed an API like below:

[image]

> Is there any way to add the user role like `admin, manager, user` to the active directory and retrieve that role when the user logs in.

And in the **`ServerApp`**, I created App roles:

[image]

Now, in the **`ClientApp`**, I added API permissions like below:

[image]

[image]

Now, I generated access token via **Client Credentials Flow** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:api://SeverAppID/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, the **App Roles** are displayed successfully like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with the second question, as I think the answer is less complicated:

To configure rules, you can use the "app roles" feature as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

They also provide you some samples (for node.js - closest I could find to react: https://github.com/azureadquickstarts/appmodelv2-webapp-openidconnect-nodejs) about how to access the information from the sign-in token including the claims. These claims include the previously defined role which may be assigned to the user.

For the first question:
Microsoft provides and article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-your-web-api

This explains how to register both your applications and how the API can securly contact graph api.